# How to get location information using react-native-location?

Tags: react-native

How to get location information by using react-native-location?

I followed [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-location), website but the example link died, I code the same as "Usage" section but it didn't work. I don't know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need to capture position, you may try the existing method of react native described [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/geolocation) . I leave you an example that I tested now:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      position => {

        console.log('geolocation: ', position);
      },
      error => Alert.alert(error.message),
      { enableHighAccuracy: false, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 1000 }
    );
  }
```

just DO NOT FORGET to put needed permission(s) in **AndroidManifest.xml** :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

also if you test your app inside a building, you probably receive nothing! to see the result, put `enableHighAccuracy: false,` in the option (i.e. look my example).

**Result:**

[image]

---

**Using react-native-location(tested for android!)**

npm install --save react-native-location
react-native link react-native-location
permissions:

**demo example:**

```
    /**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 *
 * @format
 * @flow
 */

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import RNLocation from 'react-native-location';

const instructions = Platform.select({
  ios: 'Press Cmd+R to reload,\n' + 'Cmd+D or shake for dev menu',
  android:
    'Double tap R on your keyboard to reload,\n' +
    'Shake or press menu button for dev menu',
});

type Props = {};
export default class App extends Component<Props> {
  constructor(props) {
    super();
    this.state = {
      lat: null,
      lon: null,
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    RNLocation.configure({
      distanceFilter: 5.0
    })

    RNLocation.requestPermission({
      ios: "whenInUse",
      android: {
        detail: "coarse"
      }
    }).then(granted => {
      if (granted) {
        this.locationSubscription = RNLocation.subscribeToLocationUpdates(locations => {
          console.log('locations: ', locations);
          let lat = locations[0].latitude;
          let lon = locations[0].longitude;
          console.log('locations: ', lat, lon);
          this.setState({ lat: lat, lon: lon });
        })
      }
    })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>Welcome to React Native!</Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>To get started, edit App.js</Text>
        <Text>`lat: ${this.state.lat} lon: ${this.state.lon}`</Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>{instructions}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
});
```

**result:**

[image]

if you still have problem, check the part "*Steps to manually link the library*" to ensure if evrything is setup correctly!

Comment: Thank you so much! But the request is use react-native-location only, not Geolocation API. Can we get position without using Geolocation, just react-native-location?

Comment: I did it now with react-native-location and result is good! I'll edit above with new info.

Comment: Oh! Thank you so much !!

Comment: Can I ask one more question? I want to get latitude and longitude and render them like this: <Text>{this.state.latitude}</Text>. How can I do?

Comment: How to get this info from the server? if the user is in background mode.

Comment: @RahulMishra: what do you mean by server? But generally, it is not allowed to track user's position when the app is in the background unless if you have reasonable motivation that can satisfy i.e. Apple policies, otherwise they will not hesitate to reject your app. However, if you need it only for development process(debug mode), there are options available in e.g. "User position" in background mode in the "capabilities" part of xcode that may be set.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this package

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-backgroundservice-location?activeTab=readme

Example :

```
import * as React from 'react';

import { StyleSheet, View, Button } from 'react-native';
import {
  startLocationUpdates,
  stopLocationUpdates,
  getLocation,
  getUniqueId,
} from 'react-native-backgroundservice-location';

export default function App() {
  getLocation().addListener('onLocationUpdate', (locationMap) => {
    console.log('Received :', locationMap);
  });

  const getImei = () => {
    getUniqueId()
      .then((uniqueID) => {
        console.log(uniqueID);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Button
        title="Start Location Updates"
        onPress={() =>
          startLocationUpdates(
            15000,
            'http://localhost:9951/api/BackgroundLocation/LocationLog',
            'suep'
          )
        }
      />
      <Button
        title="Stop Location Updates"
        onPress={() => stopLocationUpdates()}
      />
      <Button title="Get getUniqueId" onPress={() => getImei()} />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  box: {
    width: 60,
    height: 60,
    marginVertical: 20,
  },
});
```